# Access S3 object in SSIS RDS package and extract it

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssis, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Migrating SSIS package to RDS Server - many of the packages are used for Extracting flat files to SQL server Db . As the plan is to move to RDS Server - the way we were extracting files from File system will be now to S3 buckets . And with the limitation of RDS Server - third party tools can't be used . Would be interested for suggestions on how these Extract packages can be handled .

One of my thoughts got raised from this link :
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6619/rds-sql-server-data-import-from-amazon-s3/

With the above reference - looks like we can call S3 object from the SP which is mentioned in that link - the object gets loaded to a D folder as they had mentioned . From there on can we use a normal SSIS tasks which can point to the D folder on the specific flat file object and proceed further . Will this work or if anyone can share their experience trying in this approach or in a different approach - please share.

Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions .

Main task - Access and load an S3 object to SQL Server db with SSIS package residing in RDS.